# Using DCT and Fatou in a measure space proof

Tags: integration, analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$ and let $g \in \mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$, and assume that $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ when $n\to\infty$ for all $x\in X$. Also, assume that $g_n\leq g(x)$ for all $n\geq 1$ and all $x\in X$ Show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n d\mu =\int g d\mu$$

note that it is the extended real line.

**My thoughts**

We have to consider if the integral is finite or infinite. If it is infinite I am thinking we can use the theorem by Fatou (but still not sure on how to show that the integral of the sequences will tend to infinity). If the integral however is finite the equality would be shown by dominated convergence theorem which works since the function would be finite (and integrateable in the lebesgue sense). My troubles is in 1) if this is indeed correct, 2) how in the world you would write this up in a satisfying way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\int fd\mu <\infty$ then the result follows by DCT as you have observed. If $\int fd\mu=\infty$ the $\infty =\int fd\mu=\int \lim \inf f_nd\mu \leq \lim\inf \int f_nd\mu$ which implies that $\int f_n d\mu \to \int fd\mu$.

Comment: is the inequality a result of Fatou?

Comment: @julius1003 Yes, it is.